# How to keep categories of all variables in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with both numerical and categorical data (df1). I am creating a database that resembles the first dataframe df2, meaning it has the same column names and dtypes as df1. However, besides the names and dtypes of df1 I would also like to keep the categories of the categorical variables even if they don't appear on df2 when I create it.

So far the easiest solution I have found is to loop over all categorical variables on df2, adding the categories of each categorical variable of df1. However I believe there must be a faster/more efficient solution than the one I am proposing.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'A' : pd.Categorical(list('bbeebbaa'), categories=['e','a','b'], ordered=True),
'B' : [1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1],
'C' : pd.Categorical(list('ddeeccaa'), categories=['e','a','d', 'c'], ordered=True)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'A' : pd.Categorical(list('bbeebbbb'), categories=['e', 'b'], ordered=True),
'B' : [1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1],
'C' : pd.Categorical(list('cccccccc'), categories=['c'], ordered=True)})

categorical = ['A', 'B']
for var in categorical:
    df2[var] = df2[var].cat.add_categories(df1[var].cat.categories)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: In short, just show us some sample input, enough to illustrate your problem, and the code you have so far to solve it.  We'll be happy to help with code you've already tried, but we don't do problem solutions from stage 1.

Answer (score 0):

If all categories of df2 are in df1, you can use set_categories() function.

```
l = list(df1['A'].cat.categories)
df2['A'] = df2['A'].cat.set_categories(l)
```

Or in one line:

```
df2['A'] = df2['A'].cat.set_categories(list(df1['A'].cat.categories))
```

If both df1 and df2 contain categories unique for them, I am not sure how would I handle it - probably similarly to your way presented here.

Comment: Thanks Robert, however the solution you are proposing is for only one variable at a time, so the loop must also be done in that case. I guess there is no way to do it without a loop.